# How to display the install4j icon with update 7.0.8 when the DMG is mounted

Tags: install4j

When the install4j DMG is mounted, the previous install4j icon is no longer showing with update 7.0.8. Here is a screen shot of the mounted DMG comparing the previous version on the left and the latest 7.0.8 on the right. How do we resolve this issue?
[Mounted DMG Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffxr1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in 7.0.8 and will shortly be fixed in 7.0.9. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.